# Filtro e ordenação de tags usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer um filtro usando JavaScript puro.

Porém ao fazer o filtro e ordenar por Nome (a, b), por exemplo, só consigo ordenar os elementos do texto fora do contexto e não o bloco completo.

Por exemplo:
Preciso que o bloco `<div class="item">` seja ordenado junto ao `<span>`:

```
<div id="produto">
<div class="item">
  <span class="titulo">C</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="titulo">B</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="titulo">A</span>
</div>
```

O código que tenho é esse:

```js
    window.onload=function(){
      var div = document.querySelector('#produto'),
      para = document.querySelectorAll('.item span.titulo');
      var paraArr = [].slice.call(para).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.textContent > b.textContent ? 1 : -1;
      });
      paraArr.forEach(function (p) {
       div.appendChild(p);
  });
    }
```

```css
 .item{
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: 8px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="produto">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="titulo">C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="titulo">B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="titulo">A</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ordenar" diretamente o html é mais complicado que gerar um novo com base em dados que tenha. E até acontece que no seu caso acaba a fazer `appendChild` para adicionar um elemento que já existe no local onde está a ser adicionado mas não como filho direto e sim como neto. Também não tem forma direta de ordenar um elemento e mover outro, no caso ordenar o `titulo` e levar o `item`, sem ser navegando no DOM. Para além disso, se a ordenação é para ser feita sobre textos então deve-se basear no [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Mais simples seria ter um array com os titulos ou algo que represente a informação que tem de mostrar, e uma forma de gerar o html correspondente. Depois apenas precisa de ordenar o array e recriar o html.

Exemplo:

```js
const titulos = ["B", "C", "A"];

window.onload = function() {
  const divProduto = document.getElementById("produto");
  
  //função que cria o html de cada titulo
  const htmlTitulo = (titulo) => {
    return `<div class="item">
              <span class="titulo">${titulo}</span>
            </div>`;
  };
  
  //função que constroi o html total do produto "mapeando" cada titulo 
  //no seu html e juntando tudo para colar no div produto
  const mostrar = () => divProduto.innerHTML = titulos.map(htmlTitulo).join("");
  
  document.getElementById("crescente").addEventListener("click", () => {
    titulos.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); //ordenação com localeCompare
    mostrar();
  });
  
  document.getElementById("decrescente").addEventListener("click", () => {
    titulos.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)); //ordenação com localeCompare
    mostrar();
  });
  
  mostrar(); //quando carrega inicialmente também mostra
}
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="produto"></div>
  <button id="crescente">Crescente</button>
  <button id="decrescente">Decrescente</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada :D
realmente criar os elementos acaba se tornando mais fácil